# Scanner driver/software for Canon imageclass mf4820d multifunction laser printer on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, software-installation, scanner

I am using Canon imageclass mf4820d multifunction laser printer.  I wan to install printer and scanner driver and software for this printer on ubuntu 14.04. I am unable to print and in ubuntu. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Go on this page :
http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/printers_multifunction/imageclass_series/imageclass_mf4880dw#DriversAndSoftware

Sorry, i had to take an approching model, your printer was not listed.
Download the driver, and extract the archive.
Install both deb driver files depending on your system (32/64 bits).

Then, open 'System settings', and in the printer section, add a new printer.
In the "choose driver" menu, you will find 'MF4800...' for MF4800 series printers.
Select it and finish the installation.

Comment: Thanks Snorky35. I am downloading the driver for imageCLASS MF4890dw with File Name: Linux_UFRII_PrinterDriver_V290_us_EN.tar.gz.  I will let you know after I try it.

Comment: so in 2018 one would say go here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100924010.html and download the 3.5 version of the UFR driver; issued 8th Feb 2018; save to Downloads folder. Open a terminal and install with `cd Downloads` and `tar -zxvf linux-UFRII-drv-v350-uken.tar.gz` and `cd linux-UFRII-drv-v350-uken` and `sudo ./install.sh` and watch the terminal as it will ask questions